# Off-chain Bank Payments & oracles

Tags: oracles, chainlink, payments, off-chain

hey fellow solidity devs !

i am working on a DAO right now and one of the requirements is that members pay the DAO with fiat money off-chain (using traditional banks).

i obviously want to log that transaction on-chain and have my contracts interact with them. i searched chainlink but they dont have any oracles for this.

only thing I can think of is using chainlink to make an external API call to stripe..

thoughts? anything im missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a purely technical perspective, if your goal is to only have a log stored on chain that is meant to act as a record of DAO member contributions, then (leaving aside the discussion on whether that satisfies the tenets of decentralization and trust minimization) you can

- send deposit related data to your smart contract
- have the smart contract emit an event with relevant topics - this becomes your log

or automate this but rather than push data to your contract, you "pull" it in via automated Chainlink Keepers ([ref](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/))

- your smart contract relies on Chainlink Keepers to get triggered at regular intervals
- your smart contract then uses Chainlink Any API and adapters ([ref](https://blog.chain.link/oauth-and-api-authentication-in-smart-contracts-2/)) to connect with Stripe and get data delivered to your smartcontract
- emit event which may be a cheaper form of storage ([ref](https://blog.chain.link/events-and-logging-in-solidity/)).

Answer (score 0):

> i am working on a DAO right now and one of the requirements is that members pay the DAO with fiat money off-chain (using traditional banks).

> i obviously want to log that transaction on-chain and have my contracts interact with them. i searched chainlink but they dont have any oracles for this.

There is no point in this.

- Only you can access in the bank account
- Whatever transactions are recorded on-chain come from you
- People are explicitly trusting you or whoever has the bank account access
- Third parties cannot access the bank account to verify if any payment was actually made

There is no point to use blockchain as a glorified spreadsheet for the payments as it does not solve any problems.